# 403 stripe error - 'the provided key does not have the permissions for the end point on this account' - python requests

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, stripe-payments

[image]

I am current reverse-engineering a websites api in order to buy tickets online at an extremely fast rate, i am on the last stage where i believe i just have to post a request to stripes API with form data of my credentials but when i post it, i recieve a 403 error saying my authentication key does not have the required permissions - what am i missing? If you need any more info please let me know.

Comment: How are you testing this? Are you testing it on a live site? Do you not have a Stripe developer/test environment?

Comment: @RandomDavis - i am testing it on fixr a ticket website right now which is live and i do not have a stripe developer env. Thanks you for your response

Comment: I think the way you'll have to figure this out, then, is by monitoring the web traffic of several legitimate transactions, and see if the key changes each time or not. And also I highly suggest reading the Stripe API documentation so you can have an idea of how that key is getting generated and why it might be giving that error.

Comment: @RandomDavis i have monitored the web traffic and found that i need a 'SECRET KEY' which in unique to FIXR's account (the site im trying to use the requests on), but when inspecting the web traffic, I cannot find any headers with the secret key - so it must be hidden in some way. Any idea where or how it could be hidden - Django maybe?

Comment: From what I can see in the documentation, when a payment is made, the web browser makes a request to the website's server, with the payment info, which the website then sends over to Stripe along with the secret key. I think it must generate a special key, starting with `ek_live`, which might be a one-time key for that transaction. I think that's what your browser sends to Stripe directly. I think you'd have to, rather than sending directly to Stripe, go instead via the route that the browser normally goes through. I don't think you can skip the step that gets the `ek_live` key. Just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do in this case was just inspect every request made in that session and a private key would become apparent. Stripe didn't want me to find it but eventually I managed to. I then just used this key as a form of authentication. Much simpler than I thought